# Как написать encode программу

Tags: java

Как написать программу на java, которая бы шифровала введенную букву/набор букв согласно таблице? 
Пример: PRIVET = |>|2|/37 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опишите какие у вас есть познания в теории алгоритмов и самого языка

Comment: Программу писать это сложно. Покажите что вы уже написали?

Comment: "_Как написать программу_": 1. Придумать алгоритм. 2. Изучить функции языка, которые нужны для реализации. 3. реализовать. 4. отладить. Собственно в чем состоит ваш вопрос, какой из шагов вызывает трудности и какие

Answer (score 0):

Очень интересная задачка)) Предлагаю Вам свой вариант:

```
class Encryptor {
    private static final Map<String, String> keys = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        keys.put("A", "4");
        keys.put("B", "13");
        keys.put("C", "(");
    }

    public String encrypt(final String message) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: keys.entrySet()) {
                if(message.charAt(i) == entry.getKey().charAt(0)) {
                    builder.append(entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Пользоваться этим так:

```
    Encryptor encryptor = new Encryptor();
    System.out.println(encryptor.encrypt("ABC"));
```

Сразу подмечу, что данный вариант является простейшей реализацией. Это Вам скорее как пища для размышлений)))